# HTTParty force_encoding: encode_with_ruby_encoding

Tags: httparty

I've recently updated from 0.14.0 to version 0.15.2 and when I try to execute a #delete I'm receiving the following stacktrace:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `force_encoding' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httparty-0.15.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:280:in `encode_with_ruby_encoding'
from /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httparty-0.15.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:316:in `_encode_body'
from /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httparty-0.15.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:322:in `encode_body'
from /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httparty-0.15.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:350:in `handle_response'
from /Users//.rben`enter code here`v/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httparty-0.15.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:158:in `perform'
from /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httparty-0.15.1/lib/httparty.rb:563:in `perform_request'
from /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httparty-0.15.1/lib/httparty.rb:520:in `delete'
from /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httparty-0.15.1/lib/httparty.rb:617:in `delete'
```

I reverted back to version 0.14.0 and the issue doesn't persist. I'm a beginner to Ruby and I'm not really sure what this message is indicating.

Any assistance would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/e9f4624c1172120bbd39ddc636620a24fc9386b1/lib/httparty/request.rb#L278 you can see the `force_encoding` method referenced in the stack trace.

It appears that the response has no body, and so this method is being called on a nil object, which causes the error. This seems like a bug in HTTParty. If you can figure out reproduction steps to consistently produce this issue you could open up a github issue for the HTTParty folks to look into it further.